# How to get current data attribute value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code in php while loop :

```
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td><?php echo $blog_id; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $blog_title; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $cat_name; ?></td>
    <td class="center"><img width="50" src="<?php echo SITE_URL."assets/images/blog_images/$blog_image" ?>"/></td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo $uname; ?></td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo $added_date; ?></td>
    <td class="center"><?php echo $status; ?></td>
    <td class="center"><a data-toggle="modal" class="delete" data-id="<?php echo $blog_id; ?>" data-target="#myModal" href="<?php echo AD_SITE_URL."delete.php?name=blog&blog_id=$blog_id" ?>">Delete</td>
</tr>
```

When I click on `delete` link it's showing me a popup box with bellow code :

```
<form >
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" id="deletePost" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" value="YES">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="NO"  data-dismiss="modal">
    </div>
</form>
```

Now when I press `Yes` button it's should show me the `data-id` value from the `delete` link, but every time it's showing me same `data-id` value. How can I get each `delete` link `data-id` value using jQuery ?

**I am using following code :**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#deletePost").click(function() {
        var id = $(".delete").attr("data-id");
        alert(id);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$(".delete")` will select all elements having that class and `.attr("data-id")` will give the `data-id` attribute value of the first element from the set. When the Delete button is clicked, store the value in variable/on `Yes` button in DOM and use when `Yes` button is clicked.

Comment: `$(".delete")` selects all of the `.delete` elements in the entire document. You need to figure out how to keep track of the `data-id` for the `<a>` that was clicked (before you show the modal), and make use of that when `#deletePost` is clicked.

Comment: @JaromandaX if i use this it's showing me undefined !

Comment: @JaromandaX The `deletePost` input doesn't have a `data-id` attribute.

Comment: @JLRishe can you show me how can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to create a hidden field in your modal and populate its value each time when user click on delete link

Here is working demo

```js
$(function() {
  $(".delete").click(function() {
    id = $(this).data('id');
    $("#myModal #post-id").val(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Desc</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>title 1</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td class="center">data</td>
    <td class="center"><a data-toggle="modal" class="delete" data-id="1" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>title 2</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td class="center">data</td>
    <td class="center"><a data-toggle="modal" class="delete" data-id="2" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>title 3</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td class="center">data</td>
    <td class="center"><a data-toggle="modal" class="delete" data-id="3" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>title 4</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td class="center">data</td>
    <td class="center"><a data-toggle="modal" class="delete" data-id="4" data-target="#myModal" href="#">Delete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <form>
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Dou you want to delete</p>
              this is your hidden field for id
              <input type="text" name="id" id="post-id">
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <input type="submit" id="deletePost" class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" value="YES">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="NO" data-dismiss="modal">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal -->
```

I hope it will help

Comment: Yes, It's helped me. Thanks for that buddy. :)

Comment: Good, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var id;
$("#tableid tbody").on('click','.delete', function(e){
    // show your modal
    id = $(this).attr("data-id");
});
```

Comment: Using it's return the id value first then showing popup. I need show the poppup first then when I will click on yes button it's should show me the id value.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you click on delete button of this row then  set an additional data-id attribute to submit button

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    $('[name=submit]').attr('data-id',$(this).data('id'));
})
```

& on close the data model you can remove that attribute, (you can repeat removing attribute function when you click submit in ajax success  )

```
$('.close').on('click', function(){
   $('[name=submit]').removeAttr('data-id'))
})
```